# Correct syntax of $table.currentRow.1stCell

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my javascript :

```
$(document).on("keypress", "#desc", function(e) { //#desc to `$table.currentRow.1stCell`
  $('#cd').val() = "was change";
});
```

this is my html :

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="cd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="desc">
    </td>
  </tr>//1st row
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="cd">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="desc">
    </td>
  </tr>//2nd row
</table>
```

As you can see, i use `id` ,so when i type on either 1st or 2nd row,both 1st cell of 1st and 2nd row was changed. Im thinking of not to used `id` or `class`, but like `$table.currentRow.1stCell` but dont know what is the correct format, so i can change only the current row. Mayday please! Thanks :)

Comment: First thing you can't have somethign like this </td id = "desc">. Second thing you can't have more that once the same id on your document.

Comment: @MarioLopez ooops that was typo error. wait.

Comment: @MarioLopez ID's can actually be duplicated (at least per HTML5), not that doing such is generally advisable..

Comment: td's also do not have a value and I am not sure how you detect a keypress on a cell.

Comment: `$(this).closest("tr").find("td:first")`

Comment: @epascarello post change, theres acutally an input inside td.

Comment: That comment about id's is not correct: The value must be unique amongst all the IDs in the element's home subtree and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any space characters. [HTML5 id](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic idea of changing text of the first cell to what was typed into an input

```
$("tbody").on("change", "input", function() {
    $(this)  //input
         .closest("tr")  //finds the row associated with the input
             .find("td:first")  //returns the first cell
                 .text(this.value);  //sets the text
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yvDDp/

---

Since you changed the question's HTML:

```
$("tbody").on("change", "tr td:nth-child(2) input", function () {
    $(this) //input
        .closest("tr") //finds the row associated with the input
            .find("td:first input") //returns the first cell's input
                .val(this.value); //sets the value
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yvDDp/1/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yX4AF/ sir, i tried, but why the input is gone,the set was set to td only

Comment: Because it replaces the text. I wrote it based off your original code. Find the input, set the value.

Comment: one last sir, but i want the input to remain

Comment: FIND THE INPUT! "td:first input" set the value not text

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code work ok

```
$(document).on("keypress","#desc",function(e){ //#desc to `$table.currentRow.1stCell`
//tr  parent element find first input;
   $(this).parent().parent().find("input").first().val('was change');
    });
     });
```